# AutoCompleteTextView - Get Id when select Name

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I am getting the values from api(which list of Names with Id which i stored in model)- How to set this Name to AutoComplete and get both Name and Id on dropdown selection. 
This will set a Name in autocomplete and getting name at onItemClick but how to get ID?

**Model class**

```
public class MeetingContactModel implements Serializable {

        private String id;
        private String text;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
}
```

**MyActivity class**
OnCreate :
calling autocomplete adapter

```
setMeetingContactAuto(autoContact, contactList);

autoContact.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                strContact =(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
//                strContactCode = code.get(position);
            }
        });

private void setMeetingContactAuto(AutoCompleteTextView autoContact, final ArrayList<MeetingContactModel> xcontactList) {

        List<String> names = new AbstractList<String>() {
            @Override
            public int size() { return xcontactList.size(); }

            @Override
            public String get(int i) {
                code.clear();
                code.add(xcontactList.get(i).getText());
                return xcontactList.get(i).getText();
            }
        };
        autoContact.setThreshold(1);
        autoContact.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
    }
```

Not able to get Id - Please let me know to get it

Comment: did you getting any error

Comment: create a custom adapter for AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: `"but how to get ID"`? see the last parameter passed to `onItemClick`  method

Comment: how about changing to `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` to  `contactList.get(position).getId()`

Comment: @pskink I think he meant the `"Id"` in his dataset. As I understand it, I think He want to show both the name and id in the autofill dropdown

Comment: @Emil OP said: `"This will set a Name in autocomplete and getting name at onItemClick but how to get ID?"` - so i think he wants ID inside `onItemClick`

Comment: @pskink - need to show only Name and get both Name and Id (Dataset values) on ItemClick from autofill dropdown

Comment: where do you get `xcontactList` from? what do you need `new AbstractList` for?

Comment: xContactList is an ArrayList<MeetingContactModel> . AbstractList just to show the filtered names in dropdown list

Comment: does `xcontactList` come from some sqlite db? why dont you use some specialized `Filterable` adapter to filter out your data?

Comment: from API response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement toString() method in your model class

```
 public class MeetingContactModel implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String text;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

}


 // Fetch your selected model
 autoContact.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(requireContext(),  R.layout.spinner_item_ranking, contactList));
 autoContact.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             MeetingContactModel m=(MeetingContactModel) parent.getItem(position);
             String name=m.getText();
             String id=m.getId();
            }
        });
```

Comment: will try this & let you know

Comment: MeetingContactModel m=(MeetingContactModel) parent.getItem(position); it shows an exception as Cannot resolve method 'getItem(int)' !!! Any idea?

Comment: It works after changing getItem(int) to getItemAtPosition(int) - Thanks @Rajasekaran M

Comment: @ArnoldBrown if it's working accept answer and upvote it.

Comment: @ArnoldBrown you call `getItem()`  from you adapter object. that's why it's showing. create object for adapter and call `getItem(position)